# How can I prevent a custom node page template is used when editing a node?

Tags: theming

I'm theming some specific Drupal 9 pages with custom templates (e.g. `page--node--17.html.twig`).

That said, the theme carries over when I go to https://example.com/node/17/edit.

I only want the template to appear on the front end, not when I go in to edit a node (I want that to remain the same basic `page.html.twig` that it usually is).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are the template suggestions in the Twig debug output for one of these pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy solution would be visit /admin/appearance and at the bottom, check off:

> Use the administration theme when editing or creating content

Comment: Omg THANK YOU. Didn't even know that existed.